# Glob files *without* using a shell

Tags: shell, wildcards

I want to list files in a certain subdirectory, but I'm doing so as part of a `docker exec` inside a docker container, so I don't want to bother starting up a shell that I don't really need. Is it possible to find all the matches for a glob with a simple command line tool, and not just a shell?

For example, my current invocation is `bash -l -c 'echo /usr/local/conda-meta/*.json'`. Is it possible to simplify this using a commonly available tool, resulting in something like `globber /usr/local/conda-meta/*.json`, which would be much simpler and lighter weight?

Comment: It's a common docker idiom to create an entrypoint using the shell and then `exec` from the shell to the real program you want to run. Using the shell's exec means the process gets replaced and you don't end up with a shell running in the end.

Comment: @kojiro, in the case of builtins like `echo` or `printf`, that would be counterproductive though as using `exec` would cause bash to execute the standalone `echo`, `printf` utilities instead of running the builtins.

Comment: Is that really such a dealbreaker? I had always thought the bigger expense was the `fork`, which we avoid here, not the exec. It's hard for me to imagine a scenario where the cost of invoking /bin/echo on an already-expanded glob is worth doing work to avoid.

Comment: @kojiro, adding the `exec` is the extra work here. Also, *executing* means you can run into the limit of size of arguments+environment of `execve()`. Also note that the standalone `echo` may behave differently from the builtin one (wrt to backslash processing or option parsing for instance).

Answer (score 16):

`sh` is simple and commonly available. `sh` is the tool that is invoked to parse command lines in things like `system(cmdline)` in many languages. Many OSes including some GNU ones have stopped using `bash` (the GNU shell) to implement `sh` for the reason that it has become too bloated to do just that simple thing of parsing command lines and interpreting POSIX `sh` scripts.

Your `bash -l -c 'echo /usr/local/conda-meta/*.json'` command line is possibly being interpreted by a `sh` invocation already. So possibly you can just do:

```
printf '%s\n' /usr/local/conda-meta/*.json
```

directly. If not:

```
sh -c 'printf "%s\n" /usr/local/conda-meta/*.json'
```

You could also use `find` here. `find` doesn't do globbing but it can report file names that match patterns similar to shell ones.

```
LC_ALL=C find /usr/local/conda-meta/. ! -name . -prune -name '*.json'
```

Or with some `find` implementations:

```
LC_ALL=C find /usr/local/conda-meta -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -name '*.json'
```

(note that the `LC_ALL=C` needed here so that `*` matches any sequence of bytes, not just those that are forming valid characters in the current locale, is a shell construct. If that command line is not interpreted by a shell, you may need to change it to `env LC_ALL=C find...`)

Some differences with shell globs:

- the list of files is not sorted
- hidden files are included (you could add a `! -name '.*'` to exclude them)
- you get no output if there's no matching file. globs have that misfeature that they leave the pattern as-is unexpanded in that case.
- with the first (standard) variant, files will be output as `/usr/local/conda-meta/./file.json`.
- some globs such as `x*/y/../*z` are not easily translated (also note the differing behaviour with respect to symlinks to directories in that case).

In any case, you can't use `echo` to output arbitrary data.

My next question would be: what are you going to do with that output? With `echo`, you're outputting those file paths separated by SPC characters, and with my `printf` or `find` above, delimited by NL characters. Both `NL` and `SPC` are perfectly valid characters in file names, so those outputs are not post-processable reliable. You could use `'%s\0'` instead of `'%s\n'` (or use `find`'s `-print0` if supported), not suitable for display to a user, but post-processable.

In terms of efficiency, comparing Ubuntu 20.04's `/bin/sh` (dash 0.5.10.2) with its `find` (GNU `find` 4.7.0).

Startup time:

```
$ time (repeat 1000 sh -c '')
( repeat 1000; do; sh -c ''; done; )  0.91s user 0.66s system 105% cpu 1.483 total
$ time (repeat 1000 find . -quit)
( repeat 1000; do; find . -quit; done; )  1.35s user 1.25s system 103% cpu 2.507 total
```

Globbing some `json` files:

```
$ TIMEFMT='%U user %S system %P cpu %*E total'
$ time (repeat 1000 sh -c 'printf "%s\n" /usr/share/iso-codes/json/*.json') > /dev/null
0.95s user 0.72s system 105% cpu 1.587 total
$ time (repeat 1000  find /usr/share/iso-codes/json -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -name '*.json') > /dev/null
1.34s user 1.35s system 103% cpu 2.599 total
```

Even `bash` is hardly slower than `find` here:

```
$ time (repeat 1000 bash -c 'printf "%s\n" /usr/share/iso-codes/json/*.json') > /dev/null
1.53s user 1.36s system 102% cpu 2.808 total
```

Of course YMMV depending on the system, implementation, version of the respective utilities and the libraries they're linked against.

Now on the history note, the *glob* name actually comes from the name of a utility called `glob` in the very first versions of Unix in the early 70s. It was located in `/etc` and was invoked by `sh` as a helper to expand wildcard patterns.

You'll find a few projects online to revive that very old shell such as https://etsh.nl/. More as an exercise in archaeology, you could build the `glob` utility from there and then be able to do:

```
glob printf '%s\n' '/usr/local/conda-meta/*.json'
```

A few notes of warning though.

- those are ancient globs, `[!x]` (let alone `[^x]`) is not supported.
- it's not 8 bit safe. Actually, the 8th bit is used for *escaping* the glob operators (`$'\xe9*'` would match the same thing as `i*`, `$'\xaa*'` would match on filenames that start with `*`; the shell would set that 8th bit for the quoted characters before invoking `glob`)
- ranges like `[a-f]` match on byte value rather than collation order (in practice, that's generally an advantage IMO).
- Non-matching globs result in a `No match` error (again, probably preferably, that's something that was *broken* by the Bourne shell in the late 70s).

The `glob` functionality was later moved into the shell starting with the PWB shell and Bourne shell in the late 70s. Later, some `fnmatch()` and `glob()` functions were added to the C library to allow that feature to be used from other applications, but I'm not aware of a standard nor common utility that is a bare interface to that function. Even `perl` used to invoke `csh` in its early days to expand glob patterns.

Answer (score 6):

> Glob files *without* using a shell

The obvious documentation to read is [glob(7)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/glob.7.html).

You could write or use a C program calling [fnmatch(3)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fnmatch.3.html), [glob(3)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/glob.3.html), [nftw(3)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/nftw.3.html), [stat(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/stat.2.html), [readdir(3)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/readdir.3.html)

If you code in [Guile](https://www.gnu.org/software/guile/), [Python](https://python.org/), [Go](https://go-lang.org/), [Rust](https://rust-lang.org/), [Ocaml](https://ocaml.org/), [Common Lisp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Lisp) (e.g. [SBCL](https://sbcl.org/)) ... you'll find similar functions. With C++ look into [POCO](https://pocoproject.org/) and [Qt](https://qt.io/).

I am assuming you are using a Linux system. BTW, my interactive shell is [zsh](https://zsh.org/) (whose autocompletion facilities are IMHO preferable).

Comment: Meh... OP asked how to *"simplify this using a commonly available tool"*, not how to *"spend hours reinventing the wheel"*... (Sorry if I misunderstood your answer, but this is how it currently sounds to me. )

Comment: OP also asked about not using a shell, which is the tool to use, so reverting to the system library in a container where no shell tool should be available sounds like a good suggestion.

Comment: @Heinzi, `sh` _is_ that commonly available tool :-)

Comment: @eckes: I understood the OP's question as asking for other (more lightweight) *external utilities* as an alternative to bash, but you are right that this alternative should also be considered (especially considering the fact that other users might find this answer later). Consider my criticism retracted.

Comment: @Heinzi using the glob(3) library function is not reinventing the wheel, and it's pretty easy to use (orders of magnitude easier than spawning a shell and parsing its output). You can directly use the testcase of this [bug report](https://sourceware.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=25659) as a recipe for a standalone "glob" utility. Yes, the OP should've asked "how do I glob without a shell **in  docker exec**, (to which the answer would've probably been "You can't"), but they preferred to make their question pointlessly general. And "use glob(3)" is the perfect answer to it ;-)

Comment: BTW the only executable alternatives to shells which offer globing would be interpreters like Perl, Ruby or Python. With that prospect shell seems like a good alternative ,) also maybe you need the globing only in the build container?